# How can I loop through all <p> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, each

I want to loop through all of the paragraph elements in my document and adjust their html. Currently I use some jquery:

```
console.log("loop through <p> elements");    

$("p").each(function()
{
    console.log("next <p> element with id: " + this.id);
});
```

However only "loop through paragraph elements" appears in the console and I have a few paragraph elements with unique ids in my body:

```
<body>
    <p id="para1"> paragraph 1 </p>
    <p id="para2"> paragraph 2 </p>     
    <p id="para3"> paragraph 3 </p> 
</body>
```

I am hoping it is some kind of syntax error with the .each() loop and that someone can correct me, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $.each($("p"),function(){console.log("next <p> element with id: " + $(this).attr('id'));});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code should be:

```
$("p").each(function()
{
    console.log("next <p> element with id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Because `$(this).id` does not exist, or `this.id` is valid too.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g214e09q/)

Comment: that's correct, I forget it :)

Comment: I correct it to this and it still only outputs "loop through paragraph elements" as if there are no paragraph elements. Thank you though.

Comment: You can use `this.id`

Comment: @jctwood You need to put your code inside ready handler...

Comment: Also check whether you are adding jQuery Library.

Comment: @Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal thank you this solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```js
$("p").each(function() {
    console.log("next <p> element with id: " + this.id);
});
```

`id` is a property of `Element` instances like `this`. If you wrap it into a jQuery element, it will no longer have the `id` property, so you will have to get it using jQuery methods like `$(this).prop('id')`. That is unnecessary, though.

Comment: I correct it to this and it still only outputs "loop through paragraph elements" as if there are no paragraph elements. Thank you though.

Comment: @jctwood It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aokj1fjp/

Comment: Don't forget to put your code in a ready handler. JSFiddle omits this because it does it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects do not have an `id` property. To get the ID of the element, use `$(this).attr('id')`.

If it still does not loop through the tags, then it is probably running before the DOM has a chance to finish loading. Placing your code inside a ready handler will delay execution until the DOM has fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("loop through <p> elements");    

    $("p").each(function()
    {
        console.log("next <p> element with id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I correct it to this and it still only outputs "loop through paragraph elements" as if there are no paragraph elements. Thank you though.

Comment: @jctwood Is your code inside of a ready handler? It may be executing before the DOM is fully loaded, meaning the `<p>` tags aren't even rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined? If this is the case load the JQuery library. Add this on to the Head of your html document.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No I have included jquery correctly.